# How do I define a dependancy for use within an attribute using autofac

Tags: attributes, autofac

I have an asp.net mvc application and I am developing a custom attribute to secure some wcf end points inheriting from a CodeAccessSecurityAttribute.

I'm having difficulty finding out how I would use autofac to inject a service dependancy that I can use within this attribute.

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class SecuredResourceAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public ISecurityService SecurityService { get; set; }

    public SecuredResourceAttribute(SecurityAction action) : base(action)
    {
    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        // I need access to the SecurityService here
        // SecurityService == null :(
    }
}
```

I have tried from the application start to register for property auto wiring, but this is not working.  What's the best way to inject a dependancy into an attribute?

```
builder.RegisterType<SecuredResourceAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Thanks

Comment: My suspicion is that this is not possible, given the limitations of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are approaching this is not going to pan out for a couple reasons:

- Registering an attribute in autofac will do nothing as you're not using autofac to instantiate the attribute.
- Attributes are applied before code execution, and thus rely on constant inputs.

You're going to have to use a service location pattern inside your `CreatePermission()` method to locate the SecurityService, as I am assuming the `CreatePermission()` call comes after the container is setup (and the constructor does not!)

Keep in mind ServiceLocation will hinder your class testability, as you will have to configure/set-up the service locator for each test.

*Please use with caution*

[You should start your journey into ServiceLocation here](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) but honestly this should make you question your design. Is an attribute best suited for the role you've tasked it? Perhaps you should look into Aspect-Oriented Programming like PostSharp